# Receiving NaN when calculating elapsed time in Java

Tags: java, binary-search

I am writing a program that searches through the english dictionary using both an exhaustive and binary search. I have to print out the averages of each.
Here is the code for both. I really don't think the issue is the find and findUsingBinarySearch itself.

```
public static double measureAverageExhaustiveSearchTime(String[] queries, String[] array){
    //Measures the average number of microseconds (µs) needed to find each query, using exhaustive search.
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < queries.length; i++){
        find(queries[i], array);
    }
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double elapsedTime = (endTime - startTime);
    return (double)((elapsedTime/1000000000.0)/queries.length);
    }

   public static double measureAverageBinarySearchTime(String[] queries, String[] array){
    //Measures the average number of microseconds (µs) needed to find each query, using binary search.
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    for(int i = 0; i < queries.length; i++){
        findUsingBinarySearch(queries[i], array);
    }
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    double elapsedTime = (endTime - startTime);
    return (double)((elapsedTime/1000000000.0)/queries.length);

        //(double)(elapsedTime * 1000)/(queries.length);
}
```

My output is just:

EXHAUSTIVE SEARCH: 
NaN seconds

BINARY SEARCH: 
NaN seconds

FAILED EXHAUSTIVE SEARCH: 
NaN seconds

FAILED BINARY SEARCH: 
NaN seconds

---

When I used a much smaller file, I got this!

EXHAUSTIVE SEARCH: 
0.0 seconds

BINARY SEARCH: 
2.1E-6 seconds

FAILED EXHAUSTIVE SEARCH: 
1.0E-10 seconds

FAILED BINARY SEARCH: 
1.4E-6 seconds

Here is how I call the method, using the dictionary as both parameters, as I am trying to test how long it takes the array to binary search itself. I also use a copy of the dictionary with "zzz" appended to each word to facilitate a failed binary and exhaustive search.

```
    System.out.println("EXHAUSTIVE SEARCH: ");
System.out.println(measureAverageExhaustiveSearchTime(dictionary, dictionary)+" seconds");
System.out.println("BINARY SEARCH: ");
System.out.println(measureAverageBinarySearchTime(dictionary, dictionary)+" seconds");         
System.out.println("FAILED EXHAUSTIVE SEARCH: ");
System.out.println(measureAverageExhaustiveSearchTime(dictionaryzzz, dictionary) + " seconds");
System.out.println("FAILED BINARY SEARCH: ");
System.out.println(measureAverageBinarySearchTime(dictionaryzzz, dictionary)+" seconds");
```

I'm unsure of how to fix this.

Comment: Is it possible that queries[] is an empty array?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have enough context. In my main method, I call the measure average exhaustive/binary search methods on my dictionary, searching for every word in the dictionary inside the dictionary. :)

Comment: What is the value of this `/queries.length`?  (I don't mean what good does it do, but what is `length`?)

Comment: You realise milliseconds are not the same as nanoseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to convert from milliseconds to microseconds, you should be multiplying, instead of dividing, by 1000.

Your measureAverageExhaustiveSearchTime code:

```
return (double)((elapsedTime/1000000000.0)/queries.length);
```

This should be:

```
return (double)((elapsedTime*1000.0)/queries.length);
```

Furthermore I would avoid converting the `startTime` and `endTime` long datatypes by casting this to a double when solving for `elapsedTime`. Try to stay in one datatype. Datatype conversions sometimes results in chopped off results, or unexpected flooring of values.

Comment: it should be `elapsedTime/1000.0` to get seconds as a double.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your query array does not contain any elements. So it is empty and its length is zero (0). As an effect you get a division by zero which results in `Double.NaN`,

Comment: The query array does contain elements (as far as I know), it should contain the entire dictionary or the botched "zzz" dictionary (dictionaryzzz)

Comment: In any case you should have an empty check at the beginning of your methods to make sure.

Comment: "empty check"? I don't know what that means.

Comment: if (queries.length == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("queries must not be emtpy!");

Answer (score 0):

A `NaN` value is used to represent the result of certain invalid operations such as **dividing
zero  by  zero**.  `NaN`  constants  of  both float  and double  type  are  predefined  as
`Float.NaN` and `Double.NaN`. So, the problem is obviously with `(elapsedTime/1000000000.0)/queries.length)` and other such statement.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20021210222933/http://www.concentric.net/~ttwang/tech/javafloat.htm) article. The whole article will be extremely useful for you, but this part is especially important:

> "NaN" stands for "not a number". "Nan" is produced if a floating point
>   operation has some input parameters that cause the operation to
>   produce some undefined result. For example, 0.0 divided by 0.0 is
>   arithmetically undefined. Taking the square root of a negative number
>   is also undefined.

Now, please debug your code and watch your values, especially at your return statement. If you can see something unusual in your arithmetic operations, like 0 divided by 0, then that's the root of the problem.